# Scale image when change resolution

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have been coding using `position: absolute` and then using media query's to find different resolutions and adjust items on the screen to that resolution. After looking around people have said that its better to have a design that is fluid and adjust automatically.

I had an attempt yesterday on my login screen and I managed to get it working. On my next screen I think it is a bit more difficult as I have images that need to be scaled.

Here is my layout of my page:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.bsimplex-header-bar {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 98.7%; /* 940 divided by 960 */
}

.content {
  width: 98.7%;
  margin-top: 38px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: right;
  height: 79.5%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.bsimplex-footer-bar {
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #6a3d98;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Now I have 4 images that need to be in the middle of the screen side by side, would I wrap these 4 images in there own `div` or how can I achieve this scaling effect?

Comment: why not you use any responsive framework like bootstrap or zurb.

Comment: Have you considered using Twitter-Bootstrap framework?  It's a lot simpler to achieve your reqirements with it. For ex: You can achieve the scaling effect for images using the **img-responsive** class.

Comment: @Vijeth I have never heard of the Bootstrap framework, what is it?

Comment: It's a framework used for developing responsive and mobile-friendly websites. You can read more [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started). Also, check out some examples [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples)

Answer (score 0):

To make the images flexible, simply add max-width:100% and  height:auto. Image max-width:100% and height:auto works in IE7, but not in IE8 (yes, another weird IE bug). To fix this, you need to add width:auto\9 for IE8.

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

or use Bootstrap framework

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what is the Bootstrap framework i have never heard of it?

Comment: read here is very powerful and popular http://getbootstrap.com/ or twitter-bootstrap this is the same

Comment: I have downloaded it what do i just put the files in my project how does this make my application responsive?

Comment: first read the documentation how to use this framework, there is a class img-responsive pomoymu so, so if it applied to the image it becomes stretchable

Comment: By the way the latest version of this framework is responsive

Comment: Would i have to remake my application for it to be responsive or do i have to add a few lines on code in and the files.